# open html in python: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>

Tags: python, nginx

I have written a program on python to open a html-file in the browser if a button has been clicked. Unfortunatelly the file can be open manually in the browser via the nginx server typing in the url but not by the program. I do just get the following Error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

Here are my files:

GUI.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import urllib.request as r


class MainWindow(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master=self.parent)
        self.parent.grab_set()
        self.parent.title("Test Data Tool")
        self.parent.geometry("500x500")
        ttk.Button(self.parent, text="Show HTML", command=self.show_html).pack()     

    def show_html(self):
        r.urlopen("localhost//my_html")
```

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /Home {
            alias D:/z003e42d;
            index test.html;
        }

        location /my_html {
            alias D:/z003e42d/location/of/myHtml;
            index My.html;

            # CORS config for nginx
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                #
                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                #
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            }
            if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            }
        }
        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe i missed something inside the nginx.config but I don't know what. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try using `http://127.0.0.1/` instead of localhost and see if that works. If that's ok then it may be a DNS problem. Also, why do you have `//` instead of `/` in `urlopen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong here.

First, `"localhost//my_html"` is not a URL. You need at least a protocol, and you don't want to slashes. `"http://localhost/my_html"` is more like it.

However, this will not do what you want. It will download whatever that file is, but it won't do anything with it; it certainly won't "open it in a browser" for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your error stems from `r.urlopen("localhost//my_html")`. The fist argument to `urllib.request.urlopen` should be a valid url.This implies the full url including the protocol (either http or https).